# Print a STL Map as a table

Tags: c++, printing, stl, hashmap

I have a map defined as `map<string, vector<double> >`.

How do I print this as a table. I want the key of the map to be the title row of the table and the each column of the table will be the `vector`

Say my initial map was

```
hash = {
  "a": [1, 2, 3],
  "b": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

I want this printed as

```
a b
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

Comment: Do you need it to be justified or do you only require whitespace delimiting?

Comment: whitesapce delimiting... basically i want to write it to a csv file

Comment: Are all the vectors guaranteed to be the same size?

Comment: What do you expect if the vectors are different sizes? I'm sure you're aware that the basic problem is that your requirements are inverted compared to the natural order of iterating through your data structure.

Comment: Whitespace delimiting will not work for a CSV file (that requires comm delimiting). Those that are similar to CSV but use whitespace typically use tabs as the delimiters so fields can contain spaces.

Comment: @jerry.... if you can whitespace dlimit... then the comma delimit is trivial

Comment: @subzero: Actually, no, it's not necessarily trivial. In particular, most things will accept extra trailing whitespace, like `1 2 3 \n`, but not `1,2,3,\n`, which makes producing correct output rather less trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation using C++11 (here I expect **all vectors to have the same size**):

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void print(std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>> const& m)
{
    // Do nothing for an empty table...
    if (m.begin() == m.end()) { return; }

    for (size_t i = 0; i <= m.begin()->second.size(); i++)
    {
        for (auto const& p : m)
        {
            if (i == 0) { std::cout << p.first << " "; }
            else { std::cout << p.second[i - 1] << " "; }
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>> m = {
        { "a", { 1, 2, 3, 0 } },
        { "b", { 2, 4, 6, 1 } },
        { "c", { 9, 2, 3, 2 } }
    };

    print(m);
}
```

And here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/yJL1f%2482).

Comment: this is just printing the first three values of the vector field

Comment: @subzero: It was initially, but I've updated my answer (see the linked live example)

Answer (score 3):

Flexible for arbitrary columns and variant length

```
void print(const map<string, vector<double>> &m)
{
    size_t rows = 0;
    for (auto const &i : m)
    {
        cout << i.first << ' ';
        if (i.second.size() > rows)
            rows = i.second.size();
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
    {
        for (auto const &i : m)
            if (r < i.second.size())
                cout << i.second[r] << " ";
            else
                cout << "  ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
int main()
{ 
    map<string, vector<double> > m = {
        { "a", { 1, 2, 3}},
        { "b", { 1, 2, 3, 4}},
        { "c", { 1, 2}},
        { "d", { 1}},
        { "e", { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}}
    };
    print(m);
}
```

Output

```
 a b c d e
 1 1 1 1 1
 2 2 2   2
 3 3     3
   4     4
         5
         6
         7
```

[Live](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2UWGlz%242) source code.

Answer (score 1):

This works with vectors with different lengths:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    map<string,vector<double> > hashes;
    double arr[]={1,2,3};
    double arr2[]={1,2,3,4};
    hashes.insert(pair<string,vector<double> >("a",vector<double>(arr,arr+sizeof(arr)/sizeof(double))));
    hashes.insert(pair<string,vector<double> >("b",vector<double>(arr,arr+sizeof(arr)/sizeof(double))));
    hashes.insert(pair<string,vector<double> >("c",vector<double>(arr2,arr2+sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(double))));

    for(auto i: hashes)
    {
        cout<< i.first << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
    int max_len=0;
    for(auto i: hashes)
    {
    if(i.second.size()>max_len) max_len=i.second.size();
    }
    for(int h=0; h<max_len; h++)
    {

    for(auto i: hashes)
    {
        if(h>=i.second.size()) cout << "  ";
        else cout << i.second[h] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a b c
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
    4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<string, vector<double> > m;
    vector<double> a, b, c;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) a.push_back(i);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) b.push_back(i);
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) c.push_back(i);
    m["a"] = a;
    m["b"] = b;
    m["c"] = c;

    int n = max(max(a.size(), b.size()), c.size());
    for (map<string, vector<double> >::iterator i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); ++i)
        cout << i->first << ',';
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       for (map<string, vector<double> >::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
           cout << (i < it->second.size() ? it->second[i] : 0) << ',';
       cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I believe there are better ways to do the iteration and to deal with the trailing `,`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work for an arbitrary number of columns, each with an arbitrary number of rows.

And column names also with an arbitrary length.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void print(std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>> const& m)
{
    std::vector<size_t> columnWidths;
    std::vector< std::vector<std::string>> columns;
    size_t totalRows = 0;

    // Store all table elements, and the required width of each column
    for ( auto a : m )
    {
       std::vector<std::string> column;
       size_t width = a.first.length();
       column.push_back( a.first );
       size_t rows = 1;

       for ( auto v : a.second )
       {
          ++rows;
          std::string entry = std::to_string(v);
          width = std::max( width, entry.length() );
          column.push_back( entry );
       }
       columnWidths.push_back( width );
       columns.push_back( column );
       totalRows = std::max( totalRows, rows );
    }

    // Print all table elements
    for ( size_t row = 0; row != totalRows; ++row )
    {
        for ( size_t col = 0; col != columns.size(); ++col )
        {
            std::string entry;
            if ( columns[col].size() > row )
            {
                entry = columns[col][row];
            }
            entry.resize( columnWidths[col], ' ' );
            std::cout << entry << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>> m =
    {
        { "a", { 1, 2, 3} },
        { "a really really long string", { 1, 2, 3} },
        { "b", { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } }
    };

    print(m);
}
```